# How to assign multi colors on a screw modifier

Tags: modifiers, screw-modifier

With the screw modifier only the top or 1st material is assign. I want to assign multi colors to a screw modifier. How is it possible. Any suggestion. (I do not want to apply the modifier). Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEGQC.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Materials are assigned at the face/polygon level. The screwed edges in your question have initially no materials. So I think you should extrude/scale down the initial half circle. Assign materials to the wanted parts and use the screw.

Something like that:

[image]

Though, geometry will be non manifold and this will be visible.

To correct that, you can use a mask modifier:

Do exactly as previously but do not scale down after extruding, just stay in place. Now with these newly selected vertices create a vertex group.

Color the faces, as before (even if faces are not visible).

Then add a mask modifier after the screw, using the created vertex group:

[image]

Comment: Thanks ..........